# Given a red-black tree on n nodes, what is the maximum number of red nodes on any root to leaf path?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

This was a quiz question. I'm not sure whether my answer was right. Please help me out.

Lets say the height is h, since no two consecutive nodes (as we go up the tree) can be red, wouldn't the max number of red nodes be h/2? (h = log n)

Somehow, I feel that is not the correct answer.

Any help/input would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The max number of red nodes on a path is h/2, but h can be bigger than log_2 N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Edit ** This answer assumes a definition of height to be the number of nodes in the longest path from root to leaf (used, e.g., in [lecture notes here](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/JamesStewart/378notes/16redBlack/)) including the "virtual" black leaf nodes. More common definition counts the number of edges, and does not include the leaf nodes. With this definition the answer is `round(h/2)`, and if you include the leaf nodes in to height `round_down(h/2)`. ** Edit ends **

If you follow the rules that the root node is black as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), then the correct answer is the largest integer smaller than h/2. This is just because root and leaves are black, and half of the nodes (rounded up) in between can be red. I.e. `round((h-2)/2)`

You can also find the rule just by considering some small red-black trees of different heights.

Case `h=1` root is black -> 0 red nodes

Case 'h=2' root is black and  leaves are black -> 0  red nodes

Case `h=3` root is black, second level can be red, and leaves must be black -> max 1 red node

Case `h=4` root is black, second level can be red, third level must be black, and leaves must be black -> max 1 red node

Case `h=5` black, red, black, red, black -> max 2 red nodes.

The `h` as a function of `n` is trickier, but it can be shown that `h <= 2 log (n+1)`, which guarantees the logarithmic search time. For a proof see, e.g., [Searching and Search Trees II (page 11)](https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/wiki/_media/courses/a4m33pal/2011pal03c.pdf). The proof is based on the fact that the rules of red-black tree guarantee that a subtree starting at `x` contains at least `2^(bh(x)) - 1` internal nodes, where `bh(x)` is the black height - number of black nodes in path from root to leaf. This is proven by induction. Then by noting that at most half of the nodes are black (we are speaking of subtrees so the root can be red) that `bh(x) >= h/2`. Now using these results we get `n >= 2^bh(x) - 1 >= 2^(h/2) -1`. Solving for `h`, we get the answer `h <= 2 log(n+1)`.

As the question was a quiz, it should be enough to say that `h` is proportional to `log(n)` or even about `log(n)`.

Comment: What would h be then? How do we express it in terms of n?

Comment: @MarkJ I updated the discussion of height in terms of `n`.

Comment: [This](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/JamesStewart/378notes/16redBlack/d_RB01.gif) is a RB tree of height 2. Why can't those red nodes exist?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis My definition of height seems to be non standard/wrong. See the edit.

Comment: I see. The inductive proof might be easier if you consider black-height instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first see how few nodes (minimising *n*) are needed to make a path with 1 red node (`*` is black):

```
  *
 / \
*   R
   / \
  *   *
```

So *n* must be at least 5 when 1 red node is needed. It has 3 leaf nodes, and 2 internal nodes. Removing any node will require to drop the red node as well to stay within [the rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Properties).

If we want to extend this tree to get a path with 2 red nodes we could apply the following two steps:

1. All leaves get two black children
2. The right-most leaf (just added) is turned into a red node, and it gets 2 black children.

The dollar signs are the added black nodes compared to the prevous tree:

```
    *
   / \
  *   R
 /|  / \
$ $ *   *
   /|  / \
  $ $ $   R
         / \
        $   $
```

We choose to place that path with the red nodes on the right side; this choice does not influence the conclusions. Note that it does not help to add red nodes in other, shorter paths, as this will only increase the number of nodes without increasing the path with the most red nodes.

The number of leaf nodes (L) doubles with step 1, while the nodes that were leaves become internal nodes (I).
The second step increases both the number of internal nodes and number of leaves with 1. More formally put, we can find  these formulas, where the index *r* represents the number of red nodes:

*L<sub>1</sub> = 3*
  *I<sub>1</sub> = 2*

*L<sub>r+1</sub> = 2L<sub>r</sub> + 1*
  *I<sub>r+1</sub> = I<sub>r</sub> + L<sub>r</sub> + 1*

Put in a table for increasing *r*:

```
  r |   L |   I |  n=L+I
----+-----+-----+-------
  1 |   3 |   2 |   5
  2 |   7 |   6 |  13
  3 |  15 |  14 |  29
  4 |  31 |  30 |  61
... | ... | ... | ...
```

We can see the following is true:

*L<sub>r</sub> = 2<sup>r+1</sup> - 1*
  *I<sub>r</sub> = 2<sup>r+1</sup> - 2*

And so:

*n<sub>r</sub> = 2<sup>r+2</sup> - 3*

So we have a formula for knowing the minimum number of nodes needed to have a path with *r* red nodes. We need a different relation: the maximum for *r* when given *n*.

From the above we can derive:

*r = ⌊ log<sub>2</sub>(n+3) ⌋ - 2*